# IBM Watson Assistant: How to get random responses in the new Action skills

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

In the Watson Dialog there is an option to generate multiple responses randomly. Allowing it to feel less robotic.

[image: Picture of the UI showing 3 random text messages]

In the new Actions skills they do not have this option. Is there a way to reproduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updates:

1. SpEL is no longer supported in responses. So the sample code below will only work if assigned to a variable, then that variable is used in the response.
2. Actions now has the ability to create multiple responses.

---

If you have simple one line responses then the following code snippet will work in a response.

```
<? {
0: "Message 1",
1: "Message 2",
2: "Message 3"
}[new java.util.Random().nextInt(3)]
?>
```

The `3` in `nextInt(3)` must be the total number of random responses.

If you have more detailed responses to give then you can assign a context variable a value of `java.util.Random().nextInt(3)` (again changing 3 to total responses). Then use that as a conditional in the steps.

[image: New Actions steps showing messages]